# How to query solr with + (required) match using solrnet

Tags: solrnet

I'm using solrnet library for the interaction with solr. Is there a method in solrnet that formats a required query. I have seen the `NotQuery` which renders a `-` (not) in the query, but I now have a need for the `+` (required) in the query.

Is this possible using solrnet?

I've tried to implement a `RequiredQuery` and `RequiredQuerySerializer` similar to `NotQuery`, but I can't get it injected into the solrnet pipeline. (I know I can modify the SolrNet sourcecode, but I'd really like to keep the solrnet binary unmodified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have `RequiredQuery` implement `ISelfSerializingQuery` ([example](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/2012f8fddec1fe5d7ad448961295c443402836f6/SolrNet/SolrQueryByDistance.cs)).

A separate serializer is used for more complex cases, or to keep things neater. When using a separate `ISolrQuerySerializer`, register in your IoC container an `AggregateQuerySerializer` that includes both your serializer and the `DefaultQuerySerializer`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I didn't know about the `ISelfSerializingQuery`. I think that in my case I can't use this, as I'ld like to Require an arbitrary query (more or less the inverse of `SolrNotQuery`). For this I need a custom serializer. Is there a way of injecting this in the `DefaultQuerySerializer`?

Comment: @rjvdboon I know you said that you did not want to modify the source for SolrNet. But, IMO, it would be great to see you contribute RequiredQuery to the project as I can see other people needing this functionality as well.

Comment: @PaigeCook OK, will try. It will be my first foray into git, so it might take some time...